# SQL Server 2012: No data showing for dm_repl_schemas and cdc_schemas for DMV queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to monitor the health of a cdc implementation on one of our servers. I am expecting to see data in at least `sys.dm_cdc_log_scan_sessions`. When I issue a query, no data is returned. This behaves like a permissions thing, however, I'm an admin on the box where cdc is implemented.

I see a clue in BOL that might relate to this symptom:

> Requires view db state permissions on the "publication" database

As stupid a question as this may sound, what exactly would I be looking for to be sure I have view database state permissions? Is the publication database the database where the `cdc.captured_columns`, `cdc.change_tables`, etc. resides -- or is this referring to something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who've arrived seeking an answer:

Overall, "scan" does not mean continuous scan, so in the instance of reviewing sys.dm_cdc_log_scan_sessions, it is possible to return no data in between scanning intervals. Apparently real access to cdc data lies in the function calls. To see what they are, go to sql server's books online (BOL) and search for cdc functions (e.g. sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn). This will tap into the data you are likely looking for.